# looping the list in python and even a number but in interval of digit

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

List item

i have to loop the list and a number 
like

```
myList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" , "j", "k", "l", "m"]
```

and output of my print should come like below:

```
0 a 1
1 b 1 
2 c 2 
3 d 2
4 e 3
5 f 3
6 g 4
7 h 4
8 i 5
9 j 5
10 k 6
11 l 6
12 m 7
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow and thank you for the interesting question. However, the expectation on this forum is that you make an attempt yourself to solve the problem. Others will help you, at that point, to correct your code.

Comment: No offense but you should have tried it more, and made an attempt to search, you might have learned a lot more this way, next time give it a proper attempt.

Comment: i tried but for last holding number i couldn't understand , so asked


for i in range(0, len(myList), 1):
    print i, selectionObj[i] 

But atleast you should have helped

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index, and use integer division to calculate the 2nd number.

```
for i, s in enumerate(myList):
    print(i, s, i // 2 + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks **Brendon Abel ** , I was not having idea about enumerate , I will learn about it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Kuber if you find the answers helpful, you should upvote it and Mark it as accepted